# "TypeError: NoneType is not subscriptable" when executing multiple queries

Tags: sqlite, flask, nonetype

Member function that retrieves db.

```
def GetDb(self):
    db = getattr(g, '_database', None)
    if db is None:
        db = g._database = sqlite3.connect(self.path)       
        db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row         
    return db
```

Member function that returns list from db queries

```
def GetOrderItemsList(self, orderid):
    list = []
    with app.app_context():
        db = self.GetDb()             
        cur = db.execute('SELECT * FROM ordersList WHERE orderId = ?',[orderid])
        records = cur.fetchall(); 
        for row in records:                
            print(row)
            invid = row['inventoryId']
            OrderItem 
            OrderItem.orderId = row['orderId']
            OrderItem.productId = row['inventoryId']             
            OrderItem.productName = 'none'
            OrderItem.quantity = row['quantity']
            OrderItem.productPrice = row['price'] 
            nextcur = db.execute('SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE invId = ?', [invid]) 
             
            #nextcur = db.execute('SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE invId = 1') #works
            res = nextcur.fetchone();
            OrderItem.productName = res['invName']
            print(res['invName'])                
            list.append(OrderItem)


    return list
```

OrderItem:

```
class OrderItem(object):     
     def __init__(self, ordId, invId, name, quantity, price):
         self.orderId = ordId
         self.productId = invId
         self.productName = name
         self.quantity = quantity
         self.productPrice = price
```

Error message:

> ```
> Traceback error
> OrderItem.productName = res['invName']
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
> ```

Error

```
nextcur = db.execute('SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE invId = ?', [invid])
```

Works

```
nextcur = db.execute('SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE invId = 1')
```

Been fighting this for many hours. Searching on google. Reading questions on here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, the question should not be deleted. Somebody else might have the exact same problem you had. Please check which reason it was ("invId off" or "ambiguous column name") and write an answer of your own that explains the issue, you might help someone this way. Answering your own question is fine (even encouraged) on this site.

Comment: My oversight on invId most likely. Simplified this with a join but didn't realize what the problem was until i went into sql terminal and saw column name errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error

```
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Means that you're trying to access an object's key of an object that doesn't exist, i.e. the object is `None`.

Please check that here

```
[invid]
```

`invid` is not None, i.e. print (invid)

Also, the issue could be that here

```
res['invName']
```

`res` is `None`, please check the contents of `res` (with print, etc) before accessing `invName`, as it is `None`.

Comment: Fixed. I either had the invId off in the table or same column names in different tables was causing this. This question can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Fix with join, item instances and img for order product list.

Inventory and OrderItems

`create table inventory(invId integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, invName varchar(50), description varchar(100), invImg varchar(50) ,category integer ,quantity integer, price real);`
`create table ordersList(orderId integer, inventoryId integer, orderQuantity integer, orderPrice real);`

`class OrderItem(object):`
    `def __init__(self, ordId, invId, img, name, quantity, price):`
    `self.orderId = ordId`
    `self.productId = invId`
    `self.productName = name`
    `self.productImg = img`
    `self.quantity = quantity`
    `self.productPrice = price`

def GetOrderItemsList(orderid):
    `list = []`
    `db = get_db()`
    `cur = db.execute('SELECT orderId, inventoryId, orderQuantity, orderPrice,`
    `inventory.invName AS invName, inventory.invImg AS invImg FROM ordersList INNERJOIN`
    `inventory ON inventory.invId= ordersList.inventoryId WHERE orderId = ?', [orderid])`
    `records = cur.fetchall();`
    `for row in records:`
        `item = OrderItem(row['orderId'], row['inventoryId'],`
        `row['invImg'], row['invName'],`
        `row['orderQuantity'], row['orderPrice'] )`
        `list.append(item)`
    `return list`